# Disable menu shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, eclipse, menu

I'm using Eclipse on Ubuntu with Emacs keybindings and whenever I type <kbd>Alt-F</kbd> the File menu appears, but I want the cursor to move forward one word.

I know in programs like Terminal I can disable menu shortcuts in Preferences, but Eclipse doesn't have such a setting.

Is there a way to disable menu shortcuts globally (I never use them) or at least within Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I found was to remove the `File` menu from menubar then <kbd>Alt-F</kbd> won't match any menu shortcut and the keyboard shortcut will be triggered.

To remove a menu you go into `Window` -> `Properties` -> `Customize Perspective` and go to the `Menu Visibility` tab and uncheck `File`